# Sharing QGIS 3D visualization

Tags: qgis, export, 3d, qgis2threejs

I am using QGIS to create 3D visualizations using plugin "Qgis2threejs Exporter".

My goal is to share this with others. Right now it runs fine on my computer browser. How do I make it "sharable"?

I tried writing the output to my Onedrive "Public" folder but it does not work on other devices. Is this possible?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about OneDrive, but I can tell you what works for me at 3.12.3:

I create and edit my Qgis2threejs output to my liking and then select *File > Export to Web*, which brings up this window:

[image]

I provide an output folder on my local machine, and supply an HTML filename.  In my sceenshot, those are *C:\TEMP\TEST* and *index.html*.  After clicking the *Export* button Qgis2threejs creates a number of subfolders and files within *C:\TEMP\TEST*, including the previously named *index.html*.

As you seem to have discovered, clicking on *C:\TEMP\TEST\index.html* will display the Qgis2threejs output locally in your web browser.  But - if I understand you correctly - you also want to make that output available to others via the internet.

In my case, I have a website (lets call it *mywebsite.org*)  that came with a top-level folder named *public_html*.  I ftp *C:\TEMP\TEST* (and all its contents) from my computer to the *public_html* folder.  The website file structure now looks like: *mywebsite.org/public_html/TEST* (and all its contents).

To view the Qgis2threejs output via the internet, I enter the url *mywebsite.org/TEST/index.html* in a web browser and Voila! the Qgis2threejs output is displayed.

I don't know why browsers ignore the *public_html* folder, but there you have it.  Maybe OneDrive has a similar structure.  Good luck!